# Powershell parallel set-variable

Tags: powershell

I have a script that functions the way I want it to but it's slow. I tried using the same method in a workflow with foreach parallel but the set-variable command is not something that can be used within a workflow. I wanted to see if the way I'm doing this is incorrect and if there's a better way to get what I'm doing. The reason I want to do parallel requests is because the script can take quite a long time to complete when expanded to 20+ servers as is does each server in turn where as being able to do them all in one go would be quicker.

Below is a dumbed down version of the script (that works without parallel foreach) but it's effectively what I need to get working:

```
$servers = @("server1", "server2");
foreach ($s in $servers) {
    $counter_value = get-counter "\\$s\counter_name"
    Set-Variable -name "{s}counter" -value $counter_value
    write-host ${server1counter}
```

Comment: the sample above does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Commands not supported in workflows needs to be executed in an Inlinescript. Try (untested):

```
workflow t {
    $servers = @("server1", "server2");
    foreach -parallel ($s in $servers) {
        inlinescript {
            $counter_value = get-counter "\\$using:s\counter_name"
            Set-Variable -name "$($using:s)counter" -value $counter_value

            #write-host with a PerformanceCounterSampleSet isn't a good combination. You'll only get the typename since it's a complex type (multiple properties etc.)
            write-host (Get-Variable "$($using:s)counter" -ValueOnly)
        }
    }
}

t
```